# how server socket know network cable in unplugged in windows using c++

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

i am developing client server application in windows using c++ and winsock lib it work fine but if   it is on network and once server listening started and if i remove network cable then server doesn't shows any error in any thread so where server socket knows network cable is unplugged. 
if any body knows please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unplug a network and then plug it back in, or your Wi-Fi laptop can lose reception for a second and then pick it back up.  It would be frustrating if such resumable cases were treated as an error in all the programs we use.

From this [Winsock "newbie" FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/newbie.html):

> The previous question deals with detecting when a protocol connection is dropped normally, but what if you want to detect other problems, like unplugged network cables or crashed workstations? In these cases, the failure prevents notifying the remote peer that something is wrong. My feeling is that this is usually a feature, because the broken component might get fixed before anyone notices, so why demand that the connection be reestablished?

If you feel you have a "special needs" situation you can be aggressive with timeouts.  But I wouldn't do that unless there was a really good reason.

Answer (score 5):

While it should be possible to detect that the network cable is unplugged on the host, you will still have the same problem if the network is disrupted somewhere else between your server and the clients.

One common (if not the most common) way to solve this is to have a "keep-alive" message being sent. If no reply to that message is received within some timeout you simply close the connection and release all resources associated with it.

### Edit

A "keep-alive" message is like using the "ping" command to see if a remote machine can be reached. It is simply a message that is sent, either by the server or the client (it doesn't matter who initiate it) to see if the other end of the connection is alive and can be reached.

It can be as simple as sending the string "Are you there?" and expecting a reply containing "Yes I am". If you send it once every minute, and don't get a reply withing (for example) one minute, you can consider the connection being dead. The other end, that receives the "Are you there?", knows it will get the message once every minute. If it hasn't arrived for two minutes then the sender is no longer reachable.

If the protocol can't be modified to add such messages, then see if some other message can be used instead.

Also, remember that the best and some cases only way to know if something is wrong with a  connection is to attempt to read from the socket.

Comment: thanx for your reply but i am not properly getting what are you saying please can you explain in detail how can i sent this "keep-alive" message and who will give reply of this messge?

Comment: @yogeshpatel Added some explanations of keep-alive messages.