# How can I simulate a 'plugged network cable' (TCP/IP)?

Tags: windows, testing, tcp

I would like to test some network error conditions, but I have no network cable. Both TCP client and server application running on the same system.

Would it be a realistic simulation to use a tool like TCPView to close a connection, instead of unplugging the network cable?

---

Update:

- disconnecting using TCPView results in a 10054 error which can be handled in the application code. 10054 is a WSAECONNRESET - The connection was reset by peer. This is usually more an issue on the other side of the connection.

I have also learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8500760/80901) that "You can unplug a network and then plug it back in, or your Wi-Fi laptop can lose reception for a second and then pick it back up. It would be frustrating if such resumable cases were treated as an error in all the programs we use." (See: [how server socket know network cable in unplugged in windows using c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500664/how-server-socket-know-network-cable-in-unplugged-in-windows-using-c))

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500664/how-server-socket-know-network-cable-in-unplugged-in-windows-using-c

Comment: The best option would probably be to run your tests with a pair of virtual machines.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do to simulate a "cable disconnect" on a windows wlan card is to disable the interface by right-clicking over the interface's icon...

[image]

I did the same thing with "Local Area Connection 2" above... it doesn't matter whether the interface is wired or wireless... the mechanism is the same

Comment: both server and client are running on the same system - so disabling WLAN does not interrupt the TCP connection

Comment: If the client and server run on the same system, it's unclear how you are using wlan to communicate... please explain...

Comment: I edited my question - WLAN is only the reason for not having a cable

Comment: My answer doesn't depend on a cable being there... disabling the interface happens at the driver level... no cable is required.  What IP address are you using in your tests?

Comment: For the local tests, I use the IP address of my computer as shown by ipconfig (192.168.178.xxx). If I disable the adapter for wireless network connections, the client still can send and revceive messages.

Comment: Please post the output of `ipconfig /all` in your question

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to start connection with your external IP and then turn of WLAN? This may be acceptable for you.

If you want to close connection for only client or server you can restrict connection with firewall.

Or why not just close SERVER app and CLIENT app one after another? Close client app and you'll see what's happening with server app after losing connection and vice versa. If there is something on close event just end task via task manager.

---

*all of this:*

> *If you have both TCP client and server application running on the same
>   system*

Comment: +1, I will try using the external IP. I have removed the WLAN part from my question as it is only the reason why I have no cable attached to my test system. But I guess now it will be much easier to set up a test environment with to real computers and WLAN.