# Can I simulate pulling out the network cable?

Tags: linux, sockets

I'm running a long-running socket connection, locally. When I kill the server application it closes cleanly. I now want to see how the client behaves when it does not close cleanly. If they were on different servers I could pull out the network cable. When the connection is local I have nothing to pull. [Insert rude joke here.]

I can do `netstat -an |grep tcp | grep :80` and see the connection, which looks something like this:

```
tcp        0      0 10.1.2.3:80          10.1.2.3:40494       ESTABLISHED
```

Can I use that 40494 port number to kill or hang the socket, the same way I can use a program's PID to kill it?

Very similar question: [How can I simulate a 'plugged network cable' (TCP/IP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12795700/841830)  (That question is asking about Windows, I am on Linux)

Comment: you could probably do `ifdown eth0` or whatever your network interface is. You will neet to sudo to it and you might need to find it in `/sbin/ifdown` ifup brings it back up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the answer is "no", there is no way to kill a particular connection.

What I ended up doing was `sudo ifdown eth0` (then afterwards `sudo ifup eth0` to restore the network). Obviously this is a sledgehammer approach, as it takes down all connections.

For completeness, another approach was to guess which Apache process was running the socket connection, and kill just that process. But apart from involving guessing, that is also more application specific than the question I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Unload the kernel module for the network driver might kill it the way you want.

Pick your network interface from the list of active (eth0, eth1, etc...)

```
ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 18:A9:05:68:6F:B0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::1aa9:5ff:fe68:6fb0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
```

To find the driver module for eth0 interface

```
ls -l /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver/module
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Aug 15 18:39 module -> ../../../../module/bnx2
```

To list the kernel modules for your system run

```
lsmod | grep bnx
bnx2i                  48158  0 
cnic                   55511  1 bnx2i
bnx2                   81890  0
```

To remove the module from memory will require root or sudo access

```
rmmod -f -w bnx2
```

This is not a safe operation and you messing with the operating system in an unsafe way. Expect bad things(tm) to happen when you do this. Don't do it in a production environment. Also this may not work depending on the driver behavior itself.

That said, this is an interesting problem and I'm interested in hearing how it turns out.